# ClassCastException when casting return value from a function utilizing catalog.lookup

Tags: classloader, spring-cloud-function

Trying to use Spring Cloud Functions, I created an external jar file which contained a single class like the following:

```
Public class A implements Function<String,B>{
 Public B apply(String s){
    //...
    return instance of B;
 }
}
```

Where B is a custom object I have in a separate library. My app(separate spring boot app) can use the `Catalog.lookup()` to find the correct class from the jar and execute the function. Problem is that whenever I set the return value to B.

```
String s = ...
Function <String, B> function = catalog.lookup("A");
B objectB = function.apply(s); // line that causes error
```

I get a java.lang.ClassCastException:
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.library.B cannot be cast to com.library.B**

This app also retrieves the object model from the same library. I'm assuming the issue is because of the classloader, the app is loaded by one classLoader while the jar is loaded by "FunctionArchiveDeployer". Anyways around this? Or am I missing something completely different here?

Answer (score 0):

The `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.library.B cannot be cast to com.library.B` means that the same class is loaded twice by two different class loaders. Remember that if you are using a deployer functionality of spring-cloud-function the deployed JAR is executed in isolated and dedicated class loader. So the lookup returns `com.library.B` loaded by the class loader of the deployer and you are casting it to `com.library.B` loaded by the application class loader.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish. Like what's the business use case?